# Perl Validation::Class messages

Tags: perl, validation

I've write a custom class inherited from `Validation::Class` to define all mixins I need
Then whenever i want to use these mixins in any class, I just inherited from the custom class.
Its works perfectly but I want to customize all error messages. Example:
`message required   => '%s is required';`
So I don't have to write it in each validation field like this.

```
field username => {
   required => 1,
   messages{
       required => '%s is required'
   }
};
```

But it doesn't seems to work, it's still displaying original `Validation::Class` error message.

Can I override all messages I need in my costume class?
My custom class looks like this:

```
#Validation.pm
package Validation;
use Validation::Class;
use File::Spec ;
BEGIN {
my ($volume, $directory, $file) = File::Spec->splitpath(__FILE__); 
    push ( @INC,$directory );
}
our @ISA    = qw(Validation::Class);

# hook
build sub {
my ($self, @args) = @_; # on instantiation
};
# I have tried to but the message in here , but it doesn't work 
#message required   => '%s is reuqired';
#  data filter template
mixin filter    => {
    filters     => [qw/trim strip/],
};

# data validation template
mixin basic     => {
    max_length  => 255,
    messages    => {
        max_length   => 'Invalid %s',
    }
};
```

This is the child class inherited from my Validation class

```
#Person.pm
package person;
# Inherit my custom class instead of Validation::Class
use Validation;
our @ISA    = qw(Validation);
load role => 'Validation';
# I want to have this message in all inherited classes
# here is my problem .. this line will override required message with my custom message
# but I have many classes like this class
# is there anyway to delete this line and to write it in the parent class 
# so every child can use this message without duplicating it in them
message required   => '%s is reuqired';

# data validation rules
field username => {
    mixin       => 'filter',
    mixin       => 'basic',
    required    => 1
};
```

Comment: You should show the code of your custom class so we see what you have tried to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the messages

I have added a new mixin in the parent class (my custom Validation class) like this

```
mixin my_messages => {
    messages => {
        required   => '%s is reuqired',
        pattern    => 'Ivalid character found in %s',
     }
};
```

You can add as many messages as you can.
Then use the mixin inside all fields in any child class.
example

```
field username => {
    default     => '',
    mixin   => 'my_messages',
 };
```

Note that my_messages mixin must be the last rule in the field.